# jquery code working in firefox but not in chrome and IE 8?

Tags: jquery, cross-browser

In this code i am disabling the submit button when i clicked once and after 3000 ms i am making it enable..

This is **working fine in Firefox but not in Chrome..**

What's the wrong with this code ?

```
    // to make all the submit button disable due to avoid duplicate entries.
    $('.logged-in #edit-submit').click(function(){
        var input = this;
        input.disabled = true;
        setTimeout(function() {
           input.disabled = false;
        }, 3000);

  });
```

Comment: You can use Firebug in Firefox to diagnose the problem. Look console messages, put debug point on the last bracket in your function, etc.

Comment: I don't get the comment line ... "make all the submit button disable". With your selector you can only(!) select one single element on the page. So it can be a maximum of one submit button, otherwise your HTML is flawed.

Comment: @@LostlnLib: I tried console messages and used firebug to check the issues.. but I can't find the solution

Comment: @@devnull69: There is only one submit button in the page...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/justiceerolin/gejnA/

Looks like it works in Chrome.

Comment: There will be a page refresh for any submit button if you don't prevent the default action. And I don't see this in your code.

Comment: works great for me in chrome, too http://jsbin.com/elabij

Comment: Works in IE9 as well from Justice Erolin's jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "disabled" attribute needs "disabled" as value ([Doc](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp)). Best set and remove attributes with jQuery tools:

```
$('.logged-in #edit-submit').click(function(){
    var input = this;
    $(input).attr("disabled", "disabled");
    setTimeout(function() {
       $(input).removeAttr("disabled");
    }, 3000);
});
```

You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/christians/U9eDw/

Comment: Yes ... but .disabled is not the disabled attribute but rather the Javascript disabled property which can perfectly cope with true/false values cross browser!